# convert eclipse color theme to sublime text 2 theme

Tags: eclipse, themes, sublimetext2, sublimetext, color-scheme

I really like the theme I found on eclipse website, I would like to use it with sublime text. How can convert that theme to sublime text theme?

link to theme:
http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=7822

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a convertor but maybe with a little bit of time and my [visual sublime color scheme editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/) you could make it happen.

Comment: can it be used to do the opposite ? I really love the sunburst scheme of sublime text , and want it in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=66 Eclipse Theme mimicking Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 0):

You can get Eclipse theme forsublime here http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/Eclipse. Download the xml and keep the file "package/color-default" folder. Now go to sublime editor > Preference > Color Scheme > [Choose the Eclipse]. That's it.

Comment: He wants the sublime theme for eclipse not the eclipse theme for sublime.